# WooCommerce Order Details in Admin Dashboard

Tags: woocommerce

I set up WooCommerce and I use 2 WooCommerce websites under one domain like [www.example.com/website1](http://www.example.com/website1) and [www.example.com/website2](http://www.example.com/website2). Also, we use Woo Mobile App to see orders for both websites with Mobile App.

However, I want to see which website the order came from. So I need to add custom text to order details. I tried to show where I want to add the custom text with screenshots, both in the admin dashboard section of the website and in the woo app. I'm waiting for your ideas/solutions.

Many thanks

[screenshot 1 - Website Admin Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j45uP.jpg)

[screenshot 2 - Woo Mobile App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsBQb.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save it IN the billing info you have to save it when order is created but you can add it before billing or after billing and avoid more complications. Here is an example:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_shop_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function my_shop_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
       echo "Shop: Shop 1";
}
```